# How do you include binaries from an OS image service with docker compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to include the `xvfb` binary from the `alpine` image in the `nodejs` image.

Right now if I try to do `docker exec` on the container instance for the nodejs image, `Xvfb` won't exist, but it exists for the alpine image.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/Dockerfile-nodejs
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/nodejs
    depends_on:
      - alpine
  alpine:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./dockerfiles/Dockerfile-alpine
```

`Dockerfile-nodejs`:

```
FROM node:6.2.0

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/nodejs
WORKDIR /usr/src/nodejs

COPY package.json /usr/src/nodejs/
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/nodejs

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

`Dockerfile-alpine`:

```
FROM alpine:3.3

RUN apk update
RUN apk add xvfb

CMD ["/bin/sh"]
```

Comment: `depends_on` will only decide the order of container startup (and linking the containers by network). You won't be able to share binaries between containers.

Comment: What about using something like `links` or volumes? There must be a way

Comment: `links` only connects containers by network. Plus the alpine image is based on Alpine OS, while the node image is based on Debian, so I think the binary will not work anyway. Why not just install xvfb on the node container?

Comment: So you couldn't use `links` to run something in that container? or would you have to use some kind of messaging server as an intermediary. I didn't realize the node image was running Debian, I'll recreate the container to use alpine and install nodejs and xvfb.

Comment: I guess they're meant to be self-contained environments, with inter-container communication being done via their network address and served ports (such as with rabbitmq). But i'm still interested if there's a way to have access to resources directly